# MessagingEntityNotFoundException when peeking DLQ on azure service bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

The last two days I have started getting MessagingEntityNotFoundException when my code calls Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.PeekAsync on dead letter queue message receiver. The code have not been changed before the exception started to occur, and have been running without problems for the last two months.

The full exception message is

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: A request handler with id '56216' was not found in the entity management node $management.
```

The code runs in a time triggered Azure Function.

The code for setting up the message receivers:

```
    using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
    using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core;
    using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management;

    public class DeadLetterQueueMonitor {
       private static List<MessageReceiver> _messageReceivers;

       private async Task<List<MessageReceiver>> GetMessageReceivers(ILogger logger)
       {
         if (_messageReceivers == null)
         {
            _messageReceivers = new List<MessageReceiver>();
            var managementClient = new ManagementClient(ConnectionStrings.ServiceBusConnectionString);
            var topics = await managementClient.GetTopicsAsync();

            foreach (var topic in topics)
            {
                var subscriptions = await managementClient.GetSubscriptionsAsync(topic.Path);
                _messageReceivers.AddRange(subscriptions.Select(subscription =>
                {
                    string entityPath = EntityNameHelper.FormatDeadLetterPath(EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(topic.Path, subscription.SubscriptionName));

                    return new MessageReceiver(ConnectionStrings.ServiceBusConnectionString, entityPath);
                }));
            }
         }

         _messageReceivers = _messageReceivers
             .Select(r => r.IsClosedOrClosing ? new MessageReceiver(ConnectionStrings.ServiceBusConnectionString, r.Path) : r)
             .ToList();

         return _messageReceivers;
      }
   }
```

Any suggestions for what might be wrong?

EDIT 25/2-2019 (as response to comments):

I am using the following Nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Amqp 2.3.0
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.1.0
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication 1.0.3
```

I have added a little more context for the method that creates the MessageReceivers.

Comment: As per documentation, this error is from Setup/configuration issue. Can you please check state of service bus/app etc ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions

Need more information to comment further

Comment: it seems a lot of errors occuring recently in service bus, are you using V1 functions?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am using V2 functions, and I have other functions that access the service bus without causing problems, so I am guessing that the problem is related to either DLQ or the way I connect to them. @RahulRuikar I am not sure what kind of information you are asking for?

Comment: what are the Nuget packages are you using ? where is this _messageReceivers is declared. Is it possible for you to post that complete function ?